# Cleaning corrupt JSON fILE

Tags: json

I have recieved a json file that is corrupt. I want to read it out with AJAX but need to clean it first! Do you guys know a way to remove these u characters?

[image]

Comment: No idea why it is tagged that way

Comment: Where did you get that broken json from? Go complain on the other end.

Comment: Does the API provider guarantee that their JSON will always be corrupted with the same corruption algorithm? Is there a chance that random `u`s may be replaced in the future with `t`s or kitten pictures?

Comment: Its a static json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace u+{new line} with empty string, then it should be valid JSON.
That how you can do that in Notepad++ [image]